# SWF memory: flash player runs out of memory

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, memory-management, out-of-memory

I've got a problem with a Swf that I'm exporting from Adobe Flash CS6: in this Swf there are a lot of animations, mainly made using tweens.
However, while this animations are constantly looped, the quantity of memory used by Flash player continues to grow, and of course at a certain point flash player crashes.

How can I avoid this memory problem? (I tried compressing the images used in the animations but this method doesn't seem to work)

Comment: You are sure that it is caused by the animations? Hardly believable. How much memory is FP using? How many images and what size are you using? The compression makes no difference, btw, FP uses 4 bytes of memory per pixel no matter how you compress it.

Comment: There's a memory leak. Did you add listeners and new vars? For them to be garbage collected correctly other persistent elements should not refer them. Infinite loop => infinite listeners that can't be removed for instance. Remove them manually everytime if possible.

Comment: I'm sure this problem is caused by animations: I made some experiments, having task manager while playing the Swf. At a certain point of the animation, for example, an animated sine wave (a movieclip) comes up: right when this movieclip comes up (there is no code inside it, just a mask and a tweening movieclip which contains a png) the memory used start to grow, until flash, as you said, runs out of memory.

Comment: is there ANY code at all involved?  When you hit "F9" are there any objects listed that have timeline code?  It's very very likely code is the issue.

Comment: The only reason I can imagine that could cause this is that you are using HUGE images and you display them at the same time. You still haven't provided any useful information, btw.

Comment: There is only a keyboard event that call nextFrame().

Comment: The images I use are not bigger than 512x512.

Comment: I also noticed that when I resize the flash player window, making it smaller, the amount of memory used tend to decrease

Comment: regarding the memory, when specific animations are displayed the amount used start to increase reaching more or less 2 Gb

Comment: Post your .fla somewhere, that would be easiest.

Comment: [Dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108912540/Flash/FLA_DigitalImage.fla) The problem comes up when "MC_AnalogDigitalClock" MovieClip is playing

Comment: I am not quite sure somebody will help you out with this. It is not exactly made in the cleanest possible way. Anyway, you are assigning listeners and you never remove them. You should always free up the resources. Or at least use weak listeners.

Comment: If you saw the .Fla, I made more experiments and finally I found out the problem is the "DIGITALE" animation: I put a stop(); to prevent the animation to play and no more memory problems. Why do I have this problem with that movieclip?

Comment: Use ADobe Scout and trace the amount of different class objects. Probably you have there a class that has `cacheAsBitmap` property as true, and has a memory leak in its structure.

Comment: Since you've found that class already, you might edit this question with related info, including timeline code of that `DIGITALE` which might have a memory leak that we can help you find.

Answer (score 0):

Now I've seen people have a problem like this in my classes and the most common thing is the person is using vector graphics. Vector graphics use a ton of memory my friend had 14 gb of space need to load some tree's in his flash project because of them being set as a vector graphic. So I would take a quick look at that to see if that is the issue.

The one thing to keep in mind is a vector graphic does not lose it's quality as you make it bigger or smaller or get pixalated when you zoom in on it.